# How does one configure static proxy for Microsoft Office?

Tags: ms-word, office365, ms-office

We have an environment where you have to define static proxy manually to connect to internet. Due to several reasons we do not want to define a systemwide proxy, but rather we want to define static proxy on application basis.

In regards to Microft office we have run into an issue. Since Office needs access to Office CDN (on the internet) to download updates, we need to define a static proxy for Microsoft Office.

Does anyone know if it's possible to define a static proxy for Microsoft Office?

We do not have SCCM.

Tried to search for it on google, but no documentation from Microsoft was found.